# Joomla + Google don't work together

Tags: joomla

Here's the problem: I've used a Google Drive forms to create a form, then linked to it to my own form through action="" and name="" parameters of the form. Stuff worked like a charm when used as a plain page on my server.

Once loaded into joomla, no go. Google gives the following: "Google Drive encountered an error. If reloading the page doesn't help, please report the error."

Any suggestions on how/what things are conflicting?

Thanks!

Link to form on Joomla: http://dgm3740.inkedkeyboard.com/final/index.php/reserve-a-party (please be very considerate in entries)

Link to form as is on a server: http://test.inkedkeyboard.com/party_form_two.html

Answer (score 1):

Using the first link you provided, I was able to enter various test data without a problem.

> Tuki's Island Party Request
>   Your response has been recorded.
>   Submit
>   another response

Perhaps the problem is in your client?

Comment: I've checked the spreadsheet, and indeed your response it there... I wonder why I can't do it... I'll test on a few machines around. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: I'm using Chromium (Version 36.0.1985.125). It could be your browser causing you trouble.